# Vectorizing a function on a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I read an excel file and save each tab as a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
xla = pd.ExcelFile("file_name.xlsx")
kl=xla.sheet_names
hf_list=[]
for i in range(len(kl)):   
    hf_list.append(pd.read_excel(xla, i,index_col=0))
```

I intend to compute rank of each dataframe in the list so have written the following code.

```
def score_card(raw_list):    
    score_list=[]    
    for i in range(len(raw_list)):
        score_list.append(raw_list[i].rank(axis=1))        
    return score_list

score_list=score_card(hf_list)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to vectorize the code and avoid for loop(s) in the score_card function (and also reading the excel file).
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use parameter `sheet_name = None` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) get orderdict of DataFrames for each sheetname:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx", sheet_name = None, index_col=0)
```

Then use list comprehension:

```
score_list = [v.rank(axis=1) for k, v in dfs.items()]
```

Or create big DataFrame with `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs.values())
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the first line. But dfs is an ordered dictionary and not a list. This way I lose control of accessing in an ordered way. In other words, hf_list[n]= score_list[n] but dfs[n]!=out_df[n]

Comment: So then use `hf_list = list(dfs.values())`

Comment: Even though dfs is ordered dictionary, score_list (list comprehension method) yields result in intended order.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni - yes, exactly.

Comment: out_df[0]==hf_list[0] (in dataframe terms). Thanks again.