# Selecting dataframe columns from a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, vectorization

I have a list of pandas dataframes.

```
list_df=[df1,df2,df3,df4]
```

I access dataframes by indexing the list

```
df1=list_df[0]
df2=list_df[1]
first_n_dfs=list_df[0:n]
```

Is there a simple way of selecting 'mth column' of every dataframe in the list without for loop?
Currently I am using for loop.

```
for i in range(len(list_df)):
    print(list_df[i].iloc[:,m])
```

Please forgive if this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find a similar question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: just for clarity, what necessitates keeping the dataframes in a list like this?

Comment: I read the data from an excel file and each tab as a dataframe. This link may give some idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747815/vectorizing-a-function-on-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes/56747901?noredirect=1#comment100054131_56747901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataframes do not have the same schema (which would allow combining them), a slight optimisation you could make is to loop over the dataframes themselves:

```
for df in list_df:
    print(df.iloc[:, m])
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid for loop? I am aware of this method. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just trying to speed up. How would you combine if dataframes have same schema?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni You would use `concat`. Anyway, this is literally the only method, unless you can assume that your dataframes do have the same schema, in which case you shouldn't even be storing them in a `list` IMO

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` which will give you your result, without using a `for` loop as asked:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.iloc[:,m], list_df))
```